# adding event to calendar doesnt save to phpmyadmin database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a calendar and can delete events but i cant add events to the calendar , below i have attached the code i am using , if anyone could assist me in discovering where i am going wrong i would appreciate it.

This code is from my 'event' php file where i have my calendar

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,week,Day'
    },
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: "all_events.php",
    displayEventTime: false,
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        if (event.allDay === 'true') {
            event.allDay = true;
        } else {
            event.allDay = false;
        }
    },
   selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
   select: function (start, end, allDay) {
       var title = prompt('Event Detail:', 'Event Time:','No of People');

        if (title) {
            var start = $.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD");
            var end = $.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD");
            var time = $.formatTime(time, "HH:mm:ss");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'add_event.php',
                data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    displayMessage("Added Successfully");
                }
            });
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
            true
                    );
        } 
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
```

This is my 'add event' php file where i write the code for writing the data into the database

```html
<?php
require_once "config.php";

$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO events (title,start,end) VALUES ('". $title ."','". $start ."','". $end ."')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert);

if (! $result) {
    $result = mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: In what way does the code fail?  Are there any errors in the browser's debugging console?  Any errors in the PHP logs?  Does the JavaScript code execute as expected?  Is the AJAX call made?  Does it have the values you expect?  What is the server's response?  Is there any output from `mysqli_error`?  It's at least worth noting that your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection** which is a *very* common source of bugs.  (Not to mention a gaping security hole.)

Comment: the debugger is stating that '$.formatDate is not a function'

Comment: That's a good start.  Should it be a function?  Where is that function defined?

Comment: i need the  var start = $.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD"); to save it in a particular format so no it doesnt need to be a function

Comment: var start = $.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD");
            var end = $.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD");
            var time = $.formatTime(time, "HH:mm:ss"); - when i comment out these three lines of code the event saves to my database however the date selected doesnt save it goes to default 00/00/00